# Why pid returned by dbg:tracer() differs from dbg:get_tracer()

Tags: erlang, dbg

```
1> dbg:get_tracer().
{error,{no_tracer_on_node,nonode@nohost}}
2> dbg:tracer().
{ok,<0.33.0>}
3> dbg:get_tracer().
{ok,<0.35.0>}
```

The [document](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/dbg.html) tells: `get_tracer` returns `the process or port to which all trace messages are sent.`

But it doesn't tells clearly what `pid` returned by `dbg:tracer`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in **pman**, there are indeed two processes:

- **<0.33.0>** sits in **dbg:loop/2**
- **<0.35.0>** sits in **dbg:tracer_loop/2**

You can see what they are doing here: https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/maint/lib/runtime_tools/src/dbg.erl

I haven't dug too deep into this, but at a glance it looks like the former is doing more manager-like job and the latter actually processes traces.

Comment: Stuff like this is more about looking under the hood, rather than just reading the docs. This question is a nice example of how docs can be misleading.